# Python-Saml unable to Parse time - What time format is this?

Tags: python, saml, saml-2.0, onelogin, rfc3339

I'm working with python-saml and Azure AD B2C SAML-RP (experimental) and the assertion from Azure is throwing python-saml an error. Is the formatting from Azure off?

```
time data '2017-06-28T02:19:59.1690618Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

I see there is a solution to this at [How to parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803)

However, can you please explain for my understanding why this time does not match the format the `python-saml` library is looking for? 
What is the current format called? What is the format the library looking for? What is the difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `'2017-06-28T02:19:59.1690618Z'`, the `'1690618'`is more than 6 digits,then it can't match `'%fZ'`

As you can see in https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

`%f` is an extension to the set of format characters in the C standard (but implemented separately in datetime objects, and therefore always available). When used with the strptime() method, the `%f` directive accepts from one to six digits and zero pads on the right.